# Infinite elements animation with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite

I was looking at google and i can't find solution to make this kind of animation.
Its need to be infinite jquery left animation like this : https://gyazo.com/aad8dac7852a2ac2cf2be62cb6f8cae3 .

I want to do it using css and jquery only. Not using canvas.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can create a carousel for that, checkout http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Comment: is it possible to do something like : goto(imagewithidblabla)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:
https://jsfiddle.net/sfemv6qd/9/

The HTML is basic like so:

```
<div id="infinitescrollercontainer">
 <ul class="infinitescroller">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

The CSS is similarly basic:

```
#infinitescrollercontainer {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
}

.infinitescroller {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.infinitescroller li {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:80px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
  color: white;
  border:2px solid blue;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

The jQuery makes it all work by duplicating the original set of elements, putting the duplicated set of elements to the right of the original set of elements and then slowly moving the elements to the left. When the original set of elements moves out of sight it puts them to the right of the duplicated set of elements. It then continues to do this forever.

jQuery:

```
// select the scroller, we'll need this often
var theScroller = $('.infinitescroller');
var theScrollSpeed = 5000;
// calculate the scroller width, we do this by getting
// the width of one element and then multiplying it by the number of elements
// (after some experimentation this seemed to work best)
var theScrollerWidth = theScroller.children('li').first().outerWidth(true) * theScroller.children('li').length;
theScroller.css('width', theScrollerWidth);
// now we clone the original scroller so we have 2 to work with
var theScrollerDupe = theScroller.clone();
// adjust the left position to put it after the first scroller
theScrollerDupe.css('left',theScrollerWidth); 
theScroller.after(theScrollerDupe); // insert it into the DOM

// do the scrolling with a nice function
var doTheScrolling = function() {
  theScroller.animate({
    left: theScroller.position().left - theScrollerWidth
  }, theScrollSpeed, 'linear');
  theScrollerDupe.animate({
    left: theScrollerDupe.position().left - theScrollerWidth
  }, theScrollSpeed, 'linear', function() {
    appendScrollers(); // move the scrollers
  });
};

// whichever scroller is off to the left of the screen now needs to
// appear after the scroller we can see..
var appendScrollers = function() {
  // find out which scroller we should move by seeing which one is further to the left
  if(theScrollerDupe.position().left < theScroller.position().left) {
    theScrollerDupe.css('left',theScrollerWidth + 'px');
  } else {
    theScroller.css('left',theScrollerWidth + 'px');
  }
  doTheScrolling();
}

// do some scrolling..
doTheScrolling();
```

I'm sure there are libraries to do this for you but this is how I'd do it without a library.